# Entity Framework automatically change table name when have typo mistake

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have c# windows application, code first and automatic migration with class city:

```
 class City
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and my application context class is:

```
class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext() : base("ConnectionString")
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AppDbContext, Configuration>());
        }

        public DbSet<City> Cityes { get; set; }
    }
```

When I run my application, the database and table Cityes create successfully but there is exist a point:

I have typo mistake in type `Cityes` but in database the table name is `Cities`

[image: Sql Management studio result]

I think Entity Framework correct the typo mistake automatically... Is it true? and if Entity Framework code first engine do that how I disable that feature?

Comment: It's not fixing typos.  It uses the entity name and pluralization rules to determine the table name.  It's not looking at what you call your `DbSet`

Comment: @stephen.vakil Could you please say to me where exactly generate `Cities` ? and could we change pluralization rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable Table Pluralization, inside the `OnModelCreating` override, paste in :

```
builder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

This should fix your problem with EF pluralizing the table names.